# Oracle while exists(select ...) insert into

Tags: sql, oracle, while-loop, temporary

I am trying to insert id's into a temporary table with while loop.
TEMP_TABLE contains ID-s which = ID of entry in ID_TABLE.
ID_TABLE has two fields CON_1 and CON_2, which refer to another entry in ID_TABLE.

I want to add all CON_1 and CON_2 values from ID_TABLE into TEMP_TABLE where ID_TABLE.ID = TEMP_TABLE.ID and CON_1 or CON_2 are not already in TEMP_TABLE and then repeat the process until there are no IDs left to insert (after adding CON_1 or CON_2 to TEMP_TABLE, those ID-s might refer to ID_TABLE.ID where CON_1 or CON_2 are not already present in TEMP_TABLE).

Basically, an ID might have connections as another ID and I want to add ID, it's connections and the connections for the connections ... into TEMP_TABLE.

The query I made this far:

```
begin
    while exists(select extId
                 from (
                          select distinct case
                                              when con.CON_1 = idTable.ID
                                                  then con.CON_2
                                              else con.CON_1
                                              end
                                              as extId
                          from ID_TABLE idTable
                                   inner join TEMP_TABLE temp on idTable.ID = temp.ID
                                   inner join CONNECTIONS_TABLE con on con.CON_2 = idTable.ID
                              or con.CON_1 = idTable.ID)
                 where not exists(select ID from TEMP_TABLE where ID = extId))
        loop
            insert into TEMP_TABLE
            select extId
            from (
                     select distinct case
                                         when con.CON_1 = idTable.ID
                                             then con.CON_2
                                         else con.CON_1
                                         end
                                         as extId
                     from ID_TABLE idTable
                              inner join TEMP_TABLE temp on idTable.id = temp.ID
                              inner join CONNECTIONS_TABLE con on con.CON_2 = idTable.id
                         or con.CON_1 = idTable.ID)
            where not exists(select ID from TEMP_TABLE where ID = extId);
        end loop;
end;
```

When I run the query, I get this error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "INNER" when expecting one of the following:
   ) , with group having intersect minus order start union where
   connect
```

Running on Oracle 12c

Comment: Does Oracle 12c know `INNER JOIN`? The keyword `JOIN` was introduced in 10g, if i remember correctly... Also this seems to be PL/SQL, which never had `JOIN` clauses...

Comment: Why is your `INSERT` statement even in a loop? Just run your `INSERT` statement by itself. If there are no rows SELECTed, then nothing will get inserted.  It is a waste of resources to run the select statement twice.

Comment: If there are no rows selected, I want the loop to stop, but if there are rows, I want the loop to continue inserting while there are rows.

Oracle 12c does have INNER JOIN

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] including: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for the tables; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data that replicates the problem; details of the expected outcome once your code has run; and an explanation of the logic relating to the transformation from the input to data to the expected output. It is almost certain that using a `WHILE` loop is the wrong approach and you just want to use a single `INSERT` or `MERGE` statement but it is very difficult to reverse engineer your code to work out the better solution and an example would help.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto . . . Oracle 9i supported `JOIN` syntax and was released in 2001.

Comment: [while...loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/WHILE-LOOP-statement.html) requires a PL/SQL Boolean expression like `n > 0`, not a SQL fragment. You can drive a loop off a cursor using a [Cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/cursor-FOR-LOOP-statement.html).

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto - "_Also this seems to be PL/SQL, which never had JOIN clauses_"  No "seems to be" about it.  It is very obviously PL/SQL.  And the JOIN clause is part of the SQL statement itself, not the procedural PL/SQL code.  So if the SQL supports the JOIN (and it does) then the fact that the SQL is being issued from PL/SQL has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff @EdStevens My bad, i was mixing it up with Oracle Forms, which used PL/SQL but never had any of the `JOIN` clauses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to recursively add `CON_1` or `CON_2` values from the `CONNECTIONS_TABLE` that were connected to a prior `ID` value in both the `TEMP_TABLE` and the `ID_TABLE`.

You don't appear to need the `WHILE` loop (or even PL/SQL) and can use a single `MERGE` statement and a hierarchical query:

```sql
MERGE INTO temp_table DST
USING (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         extid
  FROM   (
    select con_1, con_2
    from   connections_table c
    START WITH EXISTS(
      SELECT 1
      FROM   ID_TABLE i
             inner join TEMP_TABLE t
             on ( i.id = t.ID )
      WHERE  i.id IN ( c.con_1, c.con_2 )
    )
    CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR con_1 IN ( con_1, con_2 )
    OR   PRIOR con_2 IN ( con_1, con_2 )
  )
  UNPIVOT (
    extid FOR con IN ( con_1 AS 1, con_2 AS 2 )
  )
) src
ON ( src.extID = dst.id )
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( id ) VALUES ( src.extid );
```

Which for the initial setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE temp_table( id ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE connections_table( con_1, con_2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 10 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE id_table ( id ) AS
SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10;
```

Would insert 3 rows and then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM temp_table;
```

Outputs:

> | ID |
> | --- |
> | 1 |
> | 2 |
> | 4 |
> | 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3241ba7c6a7f7ac7eb7f06332fe2da0c)*